# jsPlumb does not connect correctly elements inside a table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, jsplumb

I'm trying to use the connect function to link elements inside a **table**.
I have made this Stackblitz to show that the line is not connecting correctly the two elements:
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsplumb-hzfb6i)

I dont know if I am missing something here or in the connector configuration...

However with normal div seems to be working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's pretty simple, just add position relative to your Source0:

```
<td><a style="position: relative;" id="Source0">Source 0</a></td>
```

The inline style is just for the example....

[image]